# Finding root of a cubic equation.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots, symmetric-matrices, cubics

I was solving a physics statistical mechanics problem of an interacting system.

In that question, I have to find the eigenvalues of a matrix P whose elements are given by
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x} & 1 & e^{-x}\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
e^{-x} & 1 & e^{x}
\end{bmatrix}$$
I obtained the eigenvalue equation as
$$\lambda^3-\lambda^2(e^{2x} - e^{-x}+1) - \lambda(e^{-2x} - e^{2x} - 2e^{x}+1) - (e^{2x} - e^{-2x} - 2e^{x} + 2e^{-x})=0$$

I cannot go further; the solution in the textbook is stated without showing how to calculate the roots.
The eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_1 = 2\sinh (x)$$
$$\lambda_{2,3}:=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[1+2\cosh(x)\pm\sqrt{4\cosh^{2}(x)-4\cosh(x)+9}\bigg]$$

I tried finding info on how to get eigenvalues of a symmetric, definite matrix. I found that for such matrices, the eigenvalue is bounded by the lowest sum of a row and the highest sum of the row. But since the sum of rows is distinct, I can't use that to deduce the exact value of the eigenvalue.
Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: what is $\beta$ and $J$?

Comment: $\beta=1/(k_bT)$ where $T$ is the temperature, and $J>0$ is some constant.

Comment: I replaced $\beta J$ with x as $\beta$ and $ J$ are not really relevant to the problem. Replacing with x simplifies the problem.

Comment: you can use [this][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula]

Comment: Do *not* use the cubic formula.  It is a huge mess and not worth it.  Instead, find one eigenvalue by cleaning up the algebraic appearance of the matrix entries a bit more (see my answer below) and then one of the eigenvalues becomes easy to see by inspection.

Comment: If you're doing a physics problem, why wouldn't you just be happy with numerical approximation to however many decimal places you need?

Comment: @LeeMosher The chapter name from which this question was taken is "exact solution of interacting systems."

Comment: That would be a good thing to add to your question with the edit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the form of the answer, it may be easier to work with $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ from the start. To save space, I'm going to write $c$ and $s$ for $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$. A bit of determinant manipulation gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|\begin{matrix} c + s - \lambda & 1 & c - s
\\ 1 & 1-\lambda & 1
\\ c - s & 1 & c + s -\lambda\end{matrix}\right| &=& \left|\begin{matrix}
 c + s - \lambda & 1 & c - s
\\ 1 & 1-\lambda & 1
\\ \lambda - 2s & 0 & 2s -\lambda
\end{matrix}\right| \\&=& (\lambda - 2s)\left(\left|\begin{matrix}1 & c-s\\1-\lambda & 1\end{matrix}\right|-\left|\begin{matrix}c+s-\lambda & 1 \\1 & 1-\lambda\end{matrix}\right|\right)
\\ &=&(\lambda-2s)[1 - (1-\lambda)(c-s)-(c+s-\lambda)(1-\lambda) + 1]
\\ &=& (\lambda - 2s)[2(1 - c) + (2c+1)\lambda-\lambda^2]
\end{eqnarray}
The first equality comes from the fact that adding a constant multiple of one row to another doesn't change the determinant, and the second comes from the Laplace expansion along the bottom row. So we need to solve the polynomial equation
$$
(\lambda - 2\sinh x)[\lambda^2 - (2\cosh x + 1)\lambda - 2(1-\cosh x)] = 0
$$
The linear factor's solution is obvious, and the quadratic factor's solutions can be gotten through the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 4):

The $x$ only appears in your matrix in the context of $e^x$, so call that $a$ and your matrix is now
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a&1&1/a\\1&1&1\\1/a&1&a
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is so nice that fiddling around a bit leads us to the "obvious" eigenvector $(1,0,-1)$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&1&1/a\\1&1&1\\1/a&1&a
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}a-1/a\\0\\1/a-a\end{pmatrix} = (a-1/a)\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

This is why one of your eigenvalues is $2\sinh(x) = 2(e^x-e^{-x})/2 = e^x - e^{-x} = a - 1/a$.

The characteristic polynomial of the above $3 \times 3$ matrix is
$$
\det(A - \lambda I_3) = -\lambda^3 + (2a + 1)\lambda^2 + (a^2 + 2a - 2 - 1/a^2)\lambda + (a^2 - 2a + 2/a - 1/a^2).
$$
This is *not* the cubic polynomial you wrote down: my coefficient of $\lambda^2$ is $2a+1 = 2e^x + 1$ but yours has an $e^{2x}$ term.  I checked that my characteristic polynomial has root $a - 1/a$.

In any case, once you have one root $a-1/a$ of a cubic, you can factor out a linear factor $x - (a-1/a)$ and you're left with a quadratic factor, whose roots (the remaining eigenvalues) can be found with the quadratic formula.